# Disable dimming effect on disabled elements in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

As I am sure you all know, when you disabled a button or a slider or something else in the iOS, the control gets dimmed a little bit to signify that it has been disabled. How can I stop that from happening? I tried forcing alpha back to 1 after control has been disabled, but it did not work. What's the best way to address this issue?

Thanks!

Edit:
There is also a curious behavior where if I set alpha directly on a button or a slider it will remaind dimmed, but one of my parent views has this code and it somehow bypasses the dimming:

```
NSArray* childViews = [self.view subviews];
for ( UIView* childView in childViews )
{
    float alpha = 1;
    if ( self.expanded )
    {
        alpha = 0;
    }

    [childView setAlpha:alpha];
}
```

WTF?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible for system controls like sliders an switchs, but you can try to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO` to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: While this does disable the actual control, it doesn't switch to the disabled state, which I would like to look different than the normal state.

Comment: Well then subclass the control and implement your own disabled state.

Comment: It is already subclass :) That's a possible solution, I can just switch out images and what not myself. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Interface Builder, you can configure the **Disabled State** in the Attributes Inspector (cmd+alt+4). If you set the text color to the same color as the color for the Default state (but **not via "Default Color" but with the color picker**), your button looks the same for the Disabled state as for the Default state. 
However you should not disable the dimming effect as it is bad for the user experience of your app.

Comment: I don't think sliders can be configured for the disabled state through the Interface Builder. You can through the code though, and dimming still happens.